# Are there any known OIDs to get upload and downloaded data of connected hosts to a cable modem through SNMP?

Tags: networking, snmp, analysis

We are working with SNMP and required to extract monitoring information from different cable modems through SNMP.

We have been able to extract QoS parameters at CPE level and are looking to get various information of the connected hosts. We got the MAC, IP, hostname of the connected devices and are looking to get much more information about the same.

It is known that SNMP OIDs vary a lot based on the cable modem / CPE brand. What we want to be sure of is that whether any standard cable modem manufacturers like CISCO, ARRIS, HITRON maintains this information? If so, what is the OID?

Comment: No there is no such standardized OID's, every manufacturer decides on his own (usually under his own tree). On the general note there are standard OID's for traffic passed trough interface. These might work for you.

Comment: Thanks zeridon. When it is said passed thru' interface, does that mean the connections made from a device to the cable modem thru' ethernet or wifi? If this is the case then can't we establish a relationship between the device MAC and the interface instance?

Comment: IF-MIB::ifIndex.3 = INTEGER: 3
IF-MIB::ifDescr.3 = STRING: eth1
IF-MIB::ifType.3 = INTEGER: ethernetCsmacd(6)
IF-MIB::ifSpeed.3 = Gauge32: 10000000
IF-MIB::ifPhysAddress.3 = STRING: 0:50:45:xx:xx:xx
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.3 = Counter32: 2248329357
IF-MIB::ifOutOctets.3 = Counter32: 4195474669
IF-MIB::ifName.3 = STRING: eth1

Just do an snmpwalk against the modem and look for the IF-MIB

Comment: Yup I checked that. And there are a total of 30 interfaces. I was wondering how to link / map them to a connected host / device!
Btw, are there any good and easy references to understand these MIBs with actual network setup examples for a noob like me?
It would have been easier to relate things.